# Intermittent application crash when execute pthread_join

Tags: c++, pthreads

Sometimes my application crash when executing *pthread_join* and sometime it is OK. Can someone please advise what could be the problem with my code below?

*functionA* will pass some arguments and create a thread that do some calculation and store the result into *ResultPool* (global) for later use. The functionA will be called few times and each time it passes different arguments and create a new thread. All the thread_id will be store in global variable and at the end of the execution, the thread_id will be retrieved from the *ThreadIdPool* and check the completion of the thread, and then output the result from the *ResultPool*. The thread status checking and output the result are at different class and the *ThreadIdPool* is a global variable.

The threadCnt will be initialized to -1 before start of *functionA* and it is defined somewhere in my code.

```
int threadCnt;
struct ThreadData
{
  int        td_tnum;
  float      td_Freq;
  bool       td_enablePlots; 
  int        td_ifBin;
  int        td_RAT;
 };
 typedef struct ThreadData structThreadDt;
 void *thread_A(void *td);
 map<int, float> ResultPool;
 map<int, pthread_t> ThreadIdPool;
 pthread_mutex_t mutex2 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
 pthread_t thread_id[10];

 void FunctionA(int tnum, float msrFrequency, bool enablePlots)
 {
    //Pass the value to the variables.
   int ifBin;
   int RAT;

  /*
    Some calculation here and the results are assigned to ifBin and RAT
  */

  structThreadDt *td;     
  td =(structThreadDt *)malloc(sizeof(structThreadDt));
  td->td_tnum = tnum;
  td->td_Freq = msrFrequency;
  td->td_enablePlots = enablePlots; 
  td->td_ifBin = ifBin;
  td->td_RAT = RAT;

   threadCnt = threadCnt+1;
   pthread_create(&thread_id[threadCnt], NULL, thread_A, (void*) td);    

   //Store the thread id to be check for the status later.   
   ThreadIdPool[tnum]=thread_id[threadCnt]; 
  }

void* thread_A(void* td)
{
  int   ifBin; 
  int   RAT;

  bool enablePlots;
  float msrFrequency;
  int tnum;   

  structThreadDt *tds;
  tds=(structThreadDt*)td;        
  enablePlots = tds->td_enablePlots;
  msrFrequency = tds->td_Freq;
  tnum = tds->td_tnum;
  ifBin = tds->td_ifBin ;
  RAT = tds->td_RAT;       

  /*
    Do some calculation here with those ifBIN, RAT, TNUM and frequency.

  */

  //Store the result to shared variable with mutex lock
  pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex2 );
  ResultPool[tnum] = results;
  pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex2 );

  free(tds);

  return NULL;

 }
```

And here is the threadId status checking. It will first iterate the ThreadIdPool to retrieve the threadID and check the completion of the thread. If the thread is completed, it will output the result. The pthread_join execution will sometimes crash my application.

```
void StatusCheck()
{
    int tnum;


    pthread_t threadiD;
    map<int, pthread_t>::iterator itr;
    float res;

        int ret;
        //Just to make sure it has been done
        for (itr = ThreadIdPool.begin(); itr != ThreadIdPool.end(); ++itr) { 
            tnum = itr->first;
            threadiD = itr->second;          

           //Check if the thread is completed before get the results.
           ret=pthread_join(threadiD, NULL);

            if (ret!=0)
            {
                cout<<"Tnum="<<tnum<<":Error in joining thread."<<endl;
            }          

            res  =  ResultPool[tnum];
            cout<<"Results="<<res<<endl;

        } 
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use pthreads?  C++'s thread library is, IMHO, a lot easier to use and lets you get away from all of the `void*`'s.

Comment: My compiler is an older version and i do not have option to upgrade it. Gotta stick to pthread somehow.

Comment: What is `IntS`?  i.e. is `threadCnt` correctly initialized?  Also, you appear to increment `threadCnt` *before* its first use which seems slightly odd (difficult to tell from just the code shown though).

Comment: Sorry, there were typo on the variable type and i have corrected it. Also, the threadCnt is initialized to -1 some where in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a global answer :

First of all, your code is 99% C and 1% C++. I don't know why, but if you want to write C++ write C++, not C like code. Or do C, that can be what you need.
For example, you are using ton of global function, static array, raw pointers etc. Replace them with [classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes) and methods, [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), [smart_pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) etc. The STL is here to be used. You can write a class to wrap your pthread object and, instead of having free functions, use a constructor. If smart pointers are not available, replace your mallocs / free with (at least) [new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and [delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete). By the way, NULL as its equivalent in [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) in C++.

Secondly, DO NOT USE GLOBAL VARIABLES. It is not necessary in 99.99% of the case as it can be variable declared then passed as pointers / [references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) to functions.

For what can crash your program there are several things to test :
Are you variables correctly initialized ?
You said that threadCount is initialized with -1. Why ? Since it is a count it should has start at 0, or maybe it is an index and not a count.

If you can, give use more informations :

- Where are these functions used, and how, by who ?
- What is you compiler and which version are you using ?
- What is the C++ version you are using ?
- What is the goal of this projet ? Maybe there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: I initialize the threadCnt to -1 so as my threadID array will always start at 0 index. FunctionA will be called few times and each time new thread will be created with the threadID array increment by 1. Can you provide some sample code how can i safely expose the threadID to another class for the pthread_join?

Comment: Why the name of threadCnt is not maxThreadIndex if it is an index ? Or start it at 0, but use it with a -1.
What is "a few times" ? Is it inside of a loop ? Is she dynamic ?
Are you sure that thread array does not contain wrongly created or deleted thread ?
My way of doing things in C++ is to have a main as little as possible with an Application object managing my application. So you could have your threads as attributes of it.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that when you collect the data there is an access to `result_pool` without a lock. One of the threads that is still running could be accessing `result_pool` adding more keys to it at the same time you're accessing it to collect the data.